# Avoid the need to cast mocked typescript imports

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I'm importing a mocked function, but since Typescript doesn't seem to know that Jest changes the import to a mock, I have to cast the imported function before I can use mock methods like `mockReturnValue` etc.

```
jest.mock('../myImport');
import { thisFunctionIsMocked } from '../myImport'

/* ... */

(<Mock<any>>thisFunctionIsMocked).mockReturnValue(42);
```

If I don't cast the import, Typescript claims that the mock function methods don't exist.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 15):

I've been looking for the same. Unfortunately, doesn't seem to be much out there on how to handle this. Some alternatives, however.

1) Slightly different syntax for what you're already doing:

```
(thisFunctionIsMocked as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue(42);
```

2) Use `require` and cast there instead:

```
const thisFunctionIsMocked = require('../myImport') as jest.Mock;
```

Update:

`ts-jest` now has a [`mocked` helper](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/user/test-helpers#mocked) which you can use. You still need to use it when you reference mocked imports, but it means that the type signature of the original source isn't lost:

```
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';

test('direct', () => {
  foo.name();
  expect(mocked(foo.name).mock.calls).toHaveLength(1);
});
```

Comment: The mocked helper has been moved from ts-jest to the jest lib instead so you can use `jest.mocked` instead now.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation on @lobati's answer for mocked modules with more than one export that need to be handled:

```
import * as myModuleMock from 'path/to/my/module';
const { someExport, someOtherExport } = 
    require('path/to/my/__mocks__/module') as typeof myModuleMock;

// `someExport` and `someOtherExport` will be cast correctly 
/// using the type info from the actual mock
```

This avoids duplicating type info from the mock module and having to deal with each export.

Answer (score 0):

Until Jest can intercept ES6 modules to apply the mocks, this was the easiest and cleanest way for my use case.

```
jest.mock('./some/resource', () => ({
  thisFunctionIsMocked: jest.fn()
})

const { thisFunctionIsMocked } = require('./some/resource');

test('works', () => {
  thisFunctionIsMocked.mockReturnValue('cool result');
  expect(thisFunctionIsMocked()).toEqual('cool result');
});
```

Notice the use of `require` instead of `import`.

If you're using module mocks you'll need to export them using CommonJS syntax:

```
module.exports = {
  thisFunctionIsMocked: jest.fn()
};
```

Again, because Jest doesn't seem to intercept ES6 modules.

Answer (score -1):

[Module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) can be used, but not if you export the function like so:

```
export function thisFunctionIsMocked() { .... }
```

That's because you can only add to types, but you can not change existing types.
But if you export like this:

```
export interface MyMockedFunction {
    (): void;
}

export const thisFunctionIsMocked = function() { ... } as MyMockedFunction;
```

Then you should be able to then augment it:

```
jest.mock('../myImport');
import { thisFunctionIsMocked } from '../myImport'

declare module "../myImport" {
    interface MyMockedFunction {
        mockReturnValue(value: number): any;
    }
}

thisFunctionIsMocked.mockReturnValue(42);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I didn't know about module augmentation.  But to be honest, given the choice between this, and casting, I would type cast.  I'm trying to reduce the overhead and visual clutter required to write my tests.  Ideally, after calling `jest.mock`, Typescript would somehow know that the imported function is something different.  Maybe a tooling-level solution is the only option?

Comment: I've never worked with `jest` so I have no specific answer for this. What do you mean by a "tooling-level solution"?

Comment: The problem is that `jest.mock` modifies what is loaded in the `import` statement, but the Typescript compiler isn't aware of that.  By "tooling-level solution", I mean (for example) augmenting the Typescript compiler with some sort of plugin so that it knows about the modified behaviour of the import statements.